# How to get rails server to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't get me rails server to start.

I am on a mac, using a clean install of [rails3-mongoid-devise](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise), Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.8.7 patch level 174.

When I try try to start the rails server I get the following message and it never starts.

```
MBP:test-ror stephen$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Sites/workspace/test-ror/config/environment.rb:4: uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE (NameError)
    from /Users/Sites/workspace/test-ror/config.ru:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/stephen/Sites/workspace/atrack-ror/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/Sites/workspace/test-ror/config.ru:1
Stevos-MBP:atrack-ror stephen$
```

Comment: In my "environment.rb" file if I erase the content I get my server to start - albeit with errors but at least it starting. Why would this code cause my server to not start? Do I need it? The content of the file is: http://d.pr/eEnV

Comment: Why do you have `YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'` in the file?

Comment: I didn't add it in for any specific reason. It came like that with the default install of the rails3-mongoid-devise (link int he original post) install.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bundler problem: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/424. Which version of bundler are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.0.10 Looks like it might be that version that's causing the issue based on the link.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck after the upgrade. Thanks for trying to help, Aaron.

Comment: Did you uninstall the other version of bundler? Also, could it be a Rails 1.8.7 vs. 1.9.2 thing? Are you using RVM? You could try out different Rubies...

Comment: It looks like you're right about it being a ruby version problem. Looking at the [ruby 1.9.2 yaml docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/classes/YAML.html) there's an `ENGINE` constant, put there doesn't seem to be one in [the 1.8.7 yaml docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/classes/YAML.html).